# How to write firebase cloud function which responds to data change by writing a file to cloud storage bucket in one chained idiomatic promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a bucket and upload a file to the bucket. Originally I had code like this:

```
storage
.createBucket(bucketName)
.upload(tempFilePath)
```

But this gave me the error:

`TypeError: storage.createBucket(...).upload is not a function`

I assume this means I don't understand the API to storage. I would have assumed the createBucket call returns the "bucket" object which I could then use to upload to it. Am I misusing promises or misunderstanding the storage NodeJS API?

I'm using the code below. But, it still fails, AND my lint check says `Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting`.

Can anyone help me understand how to write a function that has these properties:

- If the bucket is not created, create it.
- If the bucket already exists, don't fail because it already exists, just skip the createBucket call.
- Set the bucket (if needed, looks like this is needed before calling upload in other sample code).
- Uploads the file.
- Does not have nested promises.

Complete code is here:

```
exports.writeChunk = functions.firestore
    .document('data/{userId}/data/{eventId}/chunks/chunk')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
        const projectId = 'chunk-abcdef';
        const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
        const storage = new Storage({
            projectId,
        });

        const data = change.after.data();

        // data = { "chunk" : "abcdef" }
        if( data && data.chunk ) {
            let bucketName = context.params.eventId;
            let fileName = `${context.params.eventId}-${context.params.userId}.txt`;
            const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
            console.log( `Writing out to ${tempFilePath}` );
            fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, data.chunk );

            storage
                .createBucket(bucketName)
                .then( () =>
                       storage
                       .bucket(bucketName)
                       .upload(tempFilePath)
                       .then( () => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath) )
                       .catch( err => console.error('ERROR inside upload', err))
                     )
                .catch(err => console.error('ERROR inside createBucket', err) );
        }
        else {
            console.log( "Nope!", data );
        }
```

Comment: `.then()` `.then()` is already nested... maybe have some function taking care of bucket creation?

Comment: The linter is suggesting that you shouldn't use then() inside another then() callback.

Comment: Have you tried doing `storage.bucket(bucketName).then( (bucket) => bucket.upload(tempFilePath) ).then ....`